# How can I hide the requests parameters in the URL string?

Tags: codeigniter, nginx, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using the Facebook php sdk to authenticate users from my website. However after successful authentication, the URL goes to:

```
http://URL/?state={STATE}&code={CODE}
```

How can I remove the state and the code from showing up?

I'm using Codeigniter and Nginx so .htaccess is not working..

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
rewrite ^(.+)?state=(.+)&code=(.+) www.yoursite.com$1 permanent;
```